# "How x it is" pattern

Tags: adverbs

> Over the last days , I’ve read a couple of my friends’ entries on the web about how **tremendously** picturesque places look in a snowy winter

Can one use an adverb before the adjective in the pattern above?

> how beautiful it is

vs.

> how very/amazingly beautiful it is

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's perfectly acceptable.

> He is an incredibly entertaining person.
>
> She had an elaborately ecstatic reaction to receiving the present (which made me feel like she actually didn't like it.)

Depending, on the context the overuse of adverbs in this way can be considered overly "flowery" and not good writing style, but this may also be more personal preference than any actual *rule*.

In any case your example is not grammatically correct:

> Over the last **few** days I've read a couple of my friends' entries on the web about how tremendously picturesque **some** places look [in the snow / in winter.]

"In snowy winter" makes sense, but is not idiomatic.  I would just say "in the snow" or "in winter" or "under a layer of snow" or something similar.

Comment: Thank you. I specially asked it about using adverb after how. Check modifications.

Comment: Yes, you can.  My answer still applies -- some people think this is poor writing style, but again that's personal preference.